# Using the string .replace() function to update lines in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to read a text file and then if the substring doesn't match up with expected value, I want to replace that substring with a curated value. My current code is above along with a sample .txt file.

```
def update_atom_count(self, input_file):
    count = 0
    readFile = open(input_file, 'rt')
    writeFile = open(input_file, 'wt')
    for line in readFile:
        if line[0:6] == 'ATOM  ' or line[0:6] == 'TER   ':
            count += 1
            num = line[6:11]
            if int(num) != count:
                writeFile.write(line.replace(num, str(count)))
    writeFile.close()
```

Sample .txt file:

```
ATOM   1850  OG1 THR A 225     -17.240  12.451  -7.500  1.00 62.47           O
ATOM   1851  CG2 THR A 225     -16.343  13.019  -9.660  1.00 56.69           C
ATOM   1852  N   GLN A 226     -13.575  14.217  -9.123  1.00 57.64           N
ATOM   1853  CA  GLN A 226     -12.637  14.556 -10.203  1.00 68.89           C
ATOM   1854  C   GLN A 226     -11.192  14.229  -9.816  1.00 55.30           C
ATOM   1855  O   GLN A 226     -10.255  14.468 -10.580  1.00 40.73           O
ATOM   1856  CB  GLN A 226     -12.774  16.025 -10.644  1.00 82.60           C
ATOM   1857  CG  GLN A 226     -12.264  16.309 -12.072  1.00 72.63           C
ATOM   1858  CD  GLN A 226     -12.294  17.790 -12.444  0.39 66.96           C
ATOM   1859  OE1 GLN A 226     -12.864  18.615 -11.726  1.00 74.47           O
ATOM   1860  NE2 GLN A 226     -11.673  18.130 -13.572  1.00 46.12           N
ATOM   1861  N   ASP A 227     -11.025  13.673  -8.624  1.00 32.42           N
ATOM   1862  CA  ASP A 227      -9.731  13.184  -8.201  1.00 38.31           C
ATOM   1863  C   ASP A 227      -9.679  11.646  -8.233  1.00 45.89           C
```

My goal is to replace in the second "column" of the text which is `' 1850'` with `'    1'` (the extra spacing is for formatting). The output I am expecting is:

```
ATOM      1  CG2 THR A 225     -16.343  13.019  -9.660  1.00 56.69           C
ATOM      2  N   GLN A 226     -13.575  14.217  -9.123  1.00 57.64           N
...
```

Comment: does your code throw error? if yes would you please add it to your post. are you using a class, otherwise you do not need the ```self``` parameter.

Comment: I think, file use `'\t'` character for splitting columns.Files with such as formatting can be processed using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, take a look.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you want debugging help, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Load it in a pandas dataframe, adjust the column and write to text file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

def update_atom_count(self, input_file):
    count = 0
    readFile = open(input_file, 'rt')
    writeFile = open(input_file + '.temp' , 'wt')
    for line in readFile:
        columns=line.split()
        if columns[0] in set(  ['ATOM', 'TER'] ):
            count += 1
            print( columns[0], count, " ".join(columns[2:]) , file=writeFile )
        else:
            print( line.rstrip(), file=writeFile )

    writeFile.close()
    readFile.close()
    os.rename( input_file + '.temp', input_file )
```

There are a couple of differences in our approach:

1. I am using a temporary file ( input_file + '.temp' ).  On the
   other hand, you are writing to the same file.  I felt uncomfortable
   doing that since you have the file open for read and write at the
   same time.  This is unchatered ground for me, so I avoid it and
   create temporary files ( or just work completely in memory ) .
2. I don't care about formatting - we can always post process the output
   ( for instance, we can pipe the file to `column -t`).
3. Most notably, I didn't use the replace() function.  This seemed dangerous to me since the number we are replacing may appear anywhere else on the line coincidentally.  We don't want to accidentally modify the data, just the column with the count.